# IE9 and IE10 compatibility issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, hover

I have an image which when hovered over, has blocks that appear with text on, this can be seen [here](http://www.evokeit.com/our-team/).

The HTML for this is:

```
<div class="ourteamimg">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ourteam1.jpg" alt="Our Team"/>
<div class="ourteamblocks">
<div class="ourteamblock first"><h2>Management Team</h2>
<p><?php the_field('box1'); ?></p></div>
<div class="ourteamblock second"><h2>Development Team</h2>
<p><?php the_field('box2'); ?></p></div>
<div class="ourteamblock third"><h2>Support Team</h2>
<p><?php the_field('box3'); ?></p></div>
<div class="ourteamblock fourth"><h2>Marketing Team</h2>
<p><?php the_field('box4'); ?></p></div>
<div class="ourteamblock fifth"><h2>Training Team</h2>
<p><?php the_field('box5'); ?></p></div>
<div class="ourteamblock sixth"><h2>Contractor Team</h2>
<p><?php the_field('box6'); ?></p></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for this is:

```
.ourteamblocks {
margin-top: -740px;
}
.ourteamblock {
display: block;
height: 327px;
width: 286px;
float: left;
text-indent: -9999px;
position: relative;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300!important;
}
.ourteamblock.third, .ourteamblock.sixth {
width: 288px;
}
.ourteamblock:hover {
background: #63C80A;
color: #fff;
text-indent: 0;
}
.ourteamblock:hover p, .ourteamblock:hover h2 {
position: relative;
}
```

This works fine in all versions of all browsers except for IE9 and IE10.

It is a very simple display none and display block on hover so I dont understand why this method would not work but if anyone could shed some light on this, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a shipload of negative margin you have applied there. Looks wrong to me. Could you make a reduced case in JSfiddle.net or Codepen.io?

Comment: I can't really test this in IE right now, but you'd probably be better using that team imagine as a background and having hidden overlays on top of it.

This should give you the basic idea to get your going.
http://codepen.io/isdampe/pen/yqrLC

Comment: @Paulie_D - that's right, I think I should have made the wrapper position relative and the ourteamblocks position absolute rather than negative margin to bring it up, that would have placed it at top 0 and left 0 wouldn it?

Comment: I would use a single block absolutely positioned over the image with 100% height and 100% width. Then you can use any HTML you want inside it, including floats etc.

Comment: @RichardDenton I have tried your suggestion (which I should have tried in the first place, dont know why I did it the way I did) and it loads alot quicker, have also got someone testing this in IE9 and 10 for me but have a feeling this will be fine, thank you.